# Prevent the default action. Working only in chrome

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, preventdefault

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('input[type=file]').uploadImage();
   jQuery.event.props.push('dataTransfer');
   $(".upload-cont").bind('dragenter', function (e) {
      $(".upload-cont").css("border", "1px dashed black;");
   });
   $(".upload-cont").bind('drop', function (e) {
      var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
      e.preventDefault();
   });
   $("body").bind('drop', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

In firefox 17,explorer 8 when dragging and dropping a file from desktop into browser the image will be loaded in another page. I had added preventDefault() which works perfectly in chrome. What can be done so that the action is prevented in ff,ie browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing the code to be.

```
$('body').on('dragover drop', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The dragover event has to be cancelled also for certain browser to listen to the drop. To quote the [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DragDrop/Drag_Operations)

> A listener for the dragenter and dragover events are used to indicate
>   valid drop targets, that is, places where dragged items may be
>   dropped. Most areas of a web page or application are not valid places
>   to drop data. Thus, the default handling for these events is to not
>   allow a drop.
>
> If you want to allow a drop, you must prevent the default handling by
>   cancelling the event. You can do this either by returning false from
>   an attribute-defined event listener, or by calling the event's
>   event.preventDefault method. The latter may be more feasible in a
>   function defined in a separate script.

Comment: Glad to help. I had a similar problem recently.

Comment: It would be an even better answer if it included an explanation about why the OP's code was broken and why this fixes it.

Comment: @Sparky You are right, and I added it to the answer. It took me a minute to find the source. :)