# basic drag and drop examples not working on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html, drag-and-drop

[MODIFIED THE CODE TO MAKE IT SIMPLIER] I cannot make work very simple examples of drag and drop with files using jquery and html5. I'm starting to think that it's something related with my rails configuration because nothing makes sense. I've tried many examples, to no avail.

```
<div id="drop_zone">Drop files here</div>
<output id="list"></output>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery.event.props.push('dataTransfer');

  $('#drop_zone').on('drop', function(e){
      alert("drop"); });

  $('#drop_zone').on('mouseleave', function(e){
      alert("mouseleave"); });

  $('#drop_zone').on('mouseenter', function(e){
      alert("mouseenter"); });

});

</script>
```

It works when the mouse enters, leaves, but not on the dropping of files. I'm going insane with this.

Comment: do you inspect element on your browser, to see the interact when you drag and drop or any files/elements is missing?

Comment: Yes , the interaction is missing. There is no an event when I make the drop

Comment: are you expecting when it drag and drop then will automatic upload or how? because I know that if drag and drop on the html5, the picture is generated into base64 code

Comment: I'm reading the files on the client using javascript, get some info, and then make an ajax call. All that works when using a standard file input. But I want to make it a drop box because, and it just doesn't work. If I see an example on the web, with a demo, it works. If I copy it to test it, it doesn't. I'm using rails 3.2 on an ubuntu box.

Comment: from what i see in the demo, so your case,it don't appear the image information when you drag and drop to the area right now?

Comment: Nop. It's like was dropping a file on a non-dropping allowed area. Also, the files are not images, are data files. But that shouldn't matter I think.

Comment: simplified a lot the code. Still not working.

Comment: sorry, that i could not help u much, but maybe you can take a look in this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8363464/jquery-drag-n-drop-files-how-to-get-file-info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented out in the gemfile

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

used the google jquery in the header

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-1.9.1.min.js" %>
```

and it worked...

Note that in app/assets/javascripts/application.js, you must NOT have a line that requieres jquery.

So yes, at the end it was a rails issue... have no idea why.

When I moved this small example to my bigger project it gave issues with bootstrap. But again, the bootstrap version that I was using was the one offered by the gems.